# What was the significance of The Fugitive?

Tags: character, analysis, the-sopranos

In [S04 Ep08](http://sopranos.wikia.com/wiki/Mergers_and_Acquisitions) of *The Sopranos*, titled "Mergers and Acquisitions", Tony Soprano gets a new wide screen television.  The television technician is showing Tony how to use it and the 1993 movie, [The Fugitive](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0106977/) is playing on the television.

*The Fugitive* stars actor Joe Pantoliano.  Mr. Pantoliano also starred in 21 episodes of *The Sopranos*.  Joe Pantoliano's character, Ralph Cifaretto plays a significant role in this episode and the following episode.

> Ralph Cifaretto is actually killed by Tony Soprano in Episode 9.

**What was the significance of showing *The Fugitive*?  Is there any evidence that this was an intended clue about Ralph's destiny?**